# Disable printf using freopen stdout while keeping std::cout functioning

Tags: c++

I have a piece of code that takes an `ostream` as input, which can be `std::cout` or a `std::sstream` and outputs to it.

```
void myFunction(std::ostream out)
{
    out << "output";
}
```

At the same time I want to disable the use of `printf` to any third party library, so that they do not interfere with my output in case `out == std::cout`. I can achieve this by using `freopen` to redirect `stdout` to `NUL`, but this prevents my code to correctly print to `std::out`.

Is it there a way to redirect only `printf` while keeping `std::cout` functioning?

My current solution is as follows, but the function is not agnostic of the type of out anymore.

```
void myFunction(std::ostream out)
{
    unlockStdout();  // redirect stdout to the original stdout
    out << "output";
    lockStdout(); // redirect stdout to NUL
}
```

Comment: why don't you just `dup2()` `STDOUT_FILENO` to an iostream you use for your stuff, and reopen `stdout` to `/dev/null`?

Comment: I am afraid there is no portable way only using the standard C++ library. So the best is indeed EOF advice.

Comment: @EOF can you provide an example on how to `dup2` to the iostream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im pretty sure this is not possible (at least using standard c/c++/posix). This is because printf is using STDOUT directly - the lower level. Once you redirect STDOUT it is "game over" so to speak (again: unless you go beyond standard).

You can do the opposite if you want to - that is redirect just `std::cout` without redirecting `printf`.

Comment: If I redirect stdout to NUL, printf won't be able to print anymore. This is ok. How to make cout print at this point is what I am missing.

Comment: @SimoneGaiarin thats why i wrote its more or less game over unless you want to go non-standard (which i dont know how)